# Could not write to .Net Temporary ASP.NET folder

Tags: asp.net

I upgraded from .Net 4.5.0 to 4.5.1 and the first thing I see after rebootting is, when browsing to e.g. one of the web api webservices root is:

> CS0016: Could not write to output file 
>   'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET 
>   Files\root\a119cbcc\fb0ac961\App_global.asax.utgga8tr.dll' 
>   -- 'The directory name is invalid. '

If it would be "access denied" I would have a clue but in here I am doubting, should something be recompiled / cleaned / changed ?

Comment: [Try searching](https://www.google.com/search?q=cs0016+%22could+not+write+to+output+file%22+%22the+directory+name+is+invalid%22).

Comment: No it was not in the "the question already has an answer here" (already tried) and no it was not in the first 1000 pages of Google. (so temporary folders, accounts accounts, and all that other stuff)